How to use Javascript async/await in semi-asynchronous situations? (e.g. in String.replace)
For example I'm doing a RegExp replacement on a body of text:
  text = text.replace(re, function (match, comment, op1, op2, op3, op4, op5, op6, op7) {
    if (op1 !== undefined) {
      log("processing @@");
      parseEnum(config, op1, args1);
    } else if (op2 !== undefined) {
      log("processing {{}}");
      parseConfig(config, interpolateConfig(config, op2));
      return "";
    } else if (op3 !== undefined && !configOnly) {
      log("processing [[]]");
      return await parseMacro(config, op3, asyncInstances); // <---------- HERE
    } else if (op4 !== undefined) {
      log("processing <<>>");
      await parseInclude(config, interpolateConfig(config, op4)); // <---- HERE
      return "";
    } else if (op5 !== undefined && !configOnly) {
      log("processing ~~~~");
      // TODO parseStyle(op5);
    } else if (op6 !== undefined) {
      log("processing $$");
      return interpolateConfig(config, op6);
    } else if (op7 !== undefined) {
      log("processing ^^");
    }
  });


And I need these replacements to occur synchronously, i.e. each call to the replacement function must complete before the next match and replacement. However, depending on the match, sometimes I have to call an async function. So to keep things synchronous, I decided to use await. But to do that, I also had to change the anonymous function to async:
  text = text.replace(re, async function (match, comment, op1, op2, op3, op4, op5, op6, op7) {
                          ++++++

Unfortunately however, String.replace doesn't accept an async function. I found in this answer a utility for doing just that, copied verbatim from that post by @ChrisMorgan:
async function replaceAsync(string, regexp, replacerFunction) {
    const replacements = await Promise.all(
        Array.from(string.matchAll(regexp),
            match => replacerFunction(...match)));
    let i = 0;
    return string.replace(regexp, () => replacements[i++]);
}

Using this like this (omitting code that hasn't changed)—
  text = await replaceAsync(
      text,
      re,
      async function (match, op1, args1, op2, op3, op4, op5, op6, op7) {
        ...
      }
  );

—it actually seemed to work. I thought that the replacements would still occur synchronously—well maybe the better word here is sequentially—because underneath the hood we're still calling String.replace one at a time. But later I began seeing strange results and realized I was mistaken. The replacement function was being called in parallel, and "future" replacements started processing whenever the current replacement gave up control (e.g. to fetch a file, etc. which is the reason some functions are async).
The only way I can see around this right now is to avoid async/await altogether and use Promise.resolve() instead. But I was trying to use async/await everywhere to keep a consistent style. Is there another way to do this using async/await that I'm not seeing?
Update: Hm, I cannot figure out how to solve this using Promise.resolve() either. I thought that that would essentially act like await but it does not.

can you post a block of code that actually runs and demonstrates the issue - the fragments you have are incomplete

Wow, what kind of data format is this?  Looks like some nightmare real estate data I used to have to parse.  Can you post a sample of what you're parsing?  This can be refactored a bit for sure.

If you’re surprised by how replaceAsync works, it’s probably worth reading up more to get a good understanding of how async/promises work in JavaScript. And although there are many legitimate reasons to require serial processing, if you’re seeing “strange results” when your function runs in parallel, it’s a likely indication that calls of it share state that they shouldn’t (a code smell).

This code parses and executes a proprietary markup language, some of whose "commands" can load configurations and indeed change the state for subsequent "commands" (since the commands are to be read in sequential / imperative order). Not saying this is a great situation, just explaining a bit.

To address the title and… theme: there’s no general way to do this in typical JavaScript. Async/await/promises are concerned with control flow, and you can’t insert accounting for control flow into something that didn’t already have it.
Specifically, in this case, String.prototype.replace can’t do async operations, and the above is why you had to find a specific implementation of replaceAsync. The particular behavior with respect to control flow, then, is down to the specific implementation of this async function. It starts out by calling promise-returning functions for all replacements, which usually means starting separate and parallel asynchronous tasks for each one:
const replacements = await Promise.all(
    Array.from(string.matchAll(regexp),
        match => replacerFunction(...match)));

So if you don’t want these tasks to run in parallel, wait until the previous one has finished before calling the next:
const replacements = [];

for (const match of string.matchAll(regexp)) {
    replacements.push(await replacerFunction(...match));
}


Ah! I was just beginning to realize an identical solution. I realized in truth I wasn't wanting asynchronous execution at all and just wanted to be "allowed" to use the await keyword where I thought it should go, but that was wrong. Realizing that I tried creating a replacePseudoAsync that simply acted as a wrapper, e.g. return string.replace(regexp, () => await replacerFunction(...arguments)). Not even sure ...arguments would have worked there but anyway I was cut short by the same error now that my wrapping function wasn't async. My next thought was to use a loop / keep an array. Ty!
